# GUI for Git and Mercurial on Linux (similar to Atlassian SourceTree)

Tags: linux, git, mercurial

I am looking for an app or piece of software similar to [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) for Linux (Ubuntu). SourceTree is a GUI frontend for Git and Mercurial, designed with ease of use in mind.

I know that SourceTree is not going to be ported to Linux soon, so what are the alternatives that I can use, that have similar functionality to SourceTree?

SourceTree specs:

> **Fully-Powered DVCS**
>
> SourceTree simplifies how you interact with Git and Hg repositories so you can focus on coding. Manage all your repositories, hosted or local, through SourceTree's simple interface.
>
> **Perfect for Newcomers**
>
> Simplify DVCS for your team. SourceTree can bring everyone up to speed with Git and Mercurial.
>
> - Commit, push, pull and merge changes easily with a click of a button
> - Organize your repos with the intuitive bookmarks window
> - Visualize how your work changes over time with SourceTree's log view
>
> **Powerful Enough for Experts**
>
> Make advanced Git and Mercurial developers even more productive. Review your outgoing and incoming changesets, cherry-pick between branches, patch handling, rebase, stash, shelve, and much more.
>
> **Git-flow and Hg-flow out of the box**
>
> Use Git-flow and Hg-flow with ease. Keep your repositories cleaner and your development more efficient with SourceTree's intuitive interface to Git and Hg's 'branchy' development model. A consistent development process, right out of the box.

---

I apologize if I was unclear.

I need support for Git. I use Git-flow as well well yes I want an easy-to-use It needs to support DVCS as well. The rest of the feature, i.e. integrating with my favourite editor, would be a bonus, but is not required.

Pretty much I need a tool that I can use to commit, Push, Create Pull requests, need ability to rebase, Git-flow is a must, Merge branches, and I must be able to stash my work...

Comment: What features of SourceTree do you use? It's no good if someone recommends an alternative that's good for some features you don't use but lacks features that are critical for you. For example, do you need support for Git, Hg or both? I guess you want an easy-to-use GUI, what workflows and features does it need to support? Does it need to integrate with your favorite editor, your favorite diff tool, your build system, your release system, etc.?

Comment: @Gilles I need support for Git. I use Git-flow as well, I apologize if I was unclear.. well yes I want an easy-to-use GUI, It needs to support DVCS as well. The rest of the feature, i.e. integrating with my favourite editor, would be a bonus, but is not required...

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that you use git (so an hg-only tool wouldn't help you), and to explain what features you expect beyond support for git-flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using [SmartGit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/).  It costs **80 USD**, but is **free for non-commercial use**.  It is Java-based, so it can be used on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  Along with support for all typical Git features, it supports Git-flow and has optional integration with several online Git and Hg (Mercurial) hosting services, including Github and Bitbucket.

Answer (score 9):

I generally use [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gitg). It is a GTK client for viewing and interacting with git repositories. It is a simple to use GUI that started as a GNOME replacement for [Gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/).

[image: gitg]

Some of the features of gitg:

- A quick overview of your log history.
- Right click option to create branches, tags and cherry pick commits.
- Easy to stage and unstage changes

And the drawbacks...

- It doesn't support Mercurial (which I think is not a deal breaker for you).
- Cannot merge branches
- No integration with git-flow that I know of.
- You can't push or pull changes from the repository. You can still fetch changes and you can proceed from there.
- No support for rebasing as of now.
- Cannot rename or delete branches and tags

I am not going to argue it is a replacement for SourceTree because, well, it is not quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I like SmartGit and GitKraken because they both have a "stage hunk" feature (similar to SourceTree) which let's you choose which changes in a given file to commit. I find this really useful when I've been working on different fixes/features at the same time in a single branch.

Comment: I took a look at GitKraken, and it is quite good, it is the best and closest git client to SourceTree that I have found. and it is pretty too.